# Combination problem. 2 methods

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to figure out two methods in doing these sorts of combination problems that show up on the GMAT. Mind helping me out in understanding both methods?

9 basketball players are trying out to be on a newly formed basketball team. Of these players, 5 will be chosen for the team. If 6 of the players are guards and 3 of the players are forwards, how many different teams of 3 guards and 2 forwards can be chosen?

1) Why does this method work?
6C3 * 3C2 =
6!/(3! * 3!)    *    3!/(1! * 2!) =
20              *        3        = 60

60 I believe is correct. But why do we multiply? What is going on?

2) One way to calculate the answer would be to compute the number of different teams of 5 that could be chosen out of 9 players, and then subtract out all of the teams that have too many guards or too many forwards. However, that approach will get messy. But how do I do it?

I'll start off.

9C5 = 9!/(5! * 4!) = 126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We multiply because of the "and": you want 3 guards AND 2 forwards. This is sometimes called the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

The way you did it in (1) is the easiest way, IMO:

How many 3 guard combinations are there from 6 available guards? $C(6,3)={6!\over 3!3!}=20$.

How many 2 forward combinations are there from 3 forwards? $C(3,2)=3$.

Therefore, there are $C(6,3)\cdot C(3,2)=20\cdot 3=60$ possible teams.